# calibration of two images using 8 points

Tags: .net, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

i am new to opencv and i have loaded two chessboard(http://kvisit.com/amaAY)images one next to other captured from different angles and i have computed the four corners of each image in 3d pts and i want to calibrate each image using these four corner points. can u guys please help me out how to do that?
plz ask if question requires more info.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you expand your question to include the images and the coordinates you found? It is quite easy to embed stuff like that on stack overflow.

Comment: @jilles de wit (http://kvisit.com/amaAY)-images and(kvisit.com/S8t3NAQ)--coordinates.hope this will let u understand ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good calibration comes from using chessboard calibration:

[Camera calibration](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut10.html)

Comment: i just go through the code but its capturing the image whereas i just have two images that i have given in the link..

Comment: can u please help me out that how do i use my images and 8 pts to calibrate the camera ??

Comment: well work your way with OpenCV to load the images and replace the IplImage *image = cvQueryFrame( capture ); with your loading code. Also, your images are 2 planes, and you need to supply one plane at the time. You could crop your images to get only one plane. Post more questions as you progress and plz vote up :)

Comment: Post new questions and not the same follow as comments, it will help you get a broader audience.

Comment: i got these coordinates(http://kvisit.com/S8t3NAQ) open this file in word-pad you will easily understand) and in my previous question i have given the link for images .
 how can i calibrate these images and get projection matrix for both images ?
sorry m not able to put new question,i don't know why ...  thanks

Comment: You need to understand a few bits and pieces for camera calibration. As I can see you have the 'world points' (real coordinates of your chessboard, i.e. {x,y,z}) and the 'image points' (coordinates in image , i.e. {x,y}) of your chess board. In the code they represent 'object_points' and 'image_points' respectively.

Comment: Be careful though, you need to supply the object points and image points in orderly fashion! In the vector the first object point has to match the index of the image point. You are telling the function how real world coordinates correspond to camera point coordinates. Check the function API http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/6a139876-4559-5928-912a-3c95be2a4990.htm.